# Is it possible to overwrite an export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, es6-modules

I'm building a CLI, and I'm looking for a way to overwrite an export for some templates, only if the export name exist... Is there some way to do it?

I try it in this way:

```js
function myTemplate(path, extra) {
  return `
     import * as _i from '${path}'

     if(typeof _i.someExport !== 'undefined') {
       _i.someExport = ctx => _i.someExport({ ...ctx, extra: '${extra}' }) 
     }

     export * from '${path}'
  `
}
```

*I can't touch directly the code at `${path}` because I'm building a specific CLI, and this path can be every filename outside of my workspace.*

But is throwing this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'someExport' is not exported from '../../some/path' (imported as '_i').
```

Comment: i can't say for certain its not possible, however i did try something very similar without success in node.js maybe 6 months ago, and the feedback i got then from the node.js team was that it was not possible. however, it is possible that you could get under the hood of node.js' import system, and override things manually there. i myself tried this approach but couldn't defeat the cacheing. upvoted and starred, hopefully someone else knows something. great question

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea all around. Why not just alter the code at `${path}`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know that sounds like tricky. However, I can't touch directly the code at `${path}` because I'm building a specific CLI, and this `path` can be every filename outside of my workspace.